MAUI: connect to available hotspots from inside app
I am fetching avialable wifi hotspots with this little funtion:
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAvailableNetworksAsync()
{
    IEnumerable<string> availableNetworks = null;

    // Get a handle to the Wifi
    var wifiMgr = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
    var wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver(wifiMgr);

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Start a scan and register the Broadcast receiver to get the list of Wifi Networks
        context.RegisterReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction));
        availableNetworks = wifiReceiver.Scan();
    });

    return availableNetworks;
}

This does return me a list of avialbable networks in string format. However, it ends there for me. I cant figure out what type to use to get more information over the network, other than its name. Also I would need a way to connect to that network from the app. Can someone help me out here?

You can see this case: How to retrieve active network information in android for android native.
